# Не получается заставить работать рандом выдачу с сохранением в теккущей сессии (ауки)

Tags: php, массивы

Сломал уже себе головной мозг и результата 0, хочу чтоб работала случайная выдача реквизитов с привязкой к конкретной сессии,чтоб при обновлении страницы номер не менялся, сейчас дошел до этого

```
function get_wallet($type){
    if (!(isset($_COOKIE["wallet_$type"]))){
        $arrboot = explode("\n", file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/$type"));
        $boot = "<span>".$arrboot[rand(0, count($arrboot) - 1)]."</span>";
        setcookie("wallet_$type", $boot, time()+60*60*24*30*12*10, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], false, true);
    } else {
        $boot = $_COOKIE["wallet_$type"];
    };
};


session_start(); // Стартуем сессию
if(substr($uripath,0,strlen('orders'))=='orders' && strlen($uripath)>strlen('orders')) {
    $response = str_replace("\n", "", $response);
    get_wallet('qiwi.txt');
    $response = preg_replace('/на Qiwi кошелек <b>(.*?)<\/b>/', 'на Qiwi кошелек <b>' . $boot . '</b>', trim($response));
}
if( substr($uripath,0,strlen('exchange'))=='exchange' && strlen($uripath)>strlen('exchange') ) {
    $response = str_replace("\n","",$response); 
    get_wallet('qiwi');
    $response = preg_replace('/на Qiwi кошелек <b>(.*?)<\/b>/', 'на Qiwi кошелек <b>'.$boot.'</b>', trim($response));
```

но тут почему то вообще перестал что либо выдавать. ПОмогите плиз

Comment: функция `get_wallet` ничего не возвращает. Т.е. фактически она просто пишет в куки, которые потом нигде не используются. Переменная `$boot` ниже по коду не определена

Comment: благодарю,так что надо чтоб это заработало?

Comment: Чтобы переменной `$boot` ниже `session_start();` было присвоено значение